# csv file creation using java is too much slower or taking too much time

Tags: java, csv, jboss

Firstly I select the data from the database of another system and then store in resultset then I want to make a csv file with this resultset data.

Approx. 121mb of data(300k records) taking 3 hours to making csv file with respective data. 
My code is:-

```
//connection for fetching the required data
conn=ConnInfoBrkr.newConnection(dbDriver, dbUrl, dbUser, dbPassword);
stmt=conn.createStatement();
rs=stmt.executeQuery(sqlSelect); 
colCount=rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
fileWriter = new FileWriter(dumpFileDirectory);
bwOutFile = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
while(rs.next()){
    for(int j=1; j<=colCount; ++j) {
        bwOutFile.append(fieldEncloser); 
        bwOutFile.append(rs.getString(j)); //data column
        bwOutFile.append(fieldEncloser);
        if(j<colCount){
            bwOutFile.append(fieldSeparator);  //comma
        }
    }
    // seperated the new row by newline
    bwOutFile.append(lineSeparator);
    bwOutFile.flush();
}
bwOutFile.close();
rs.close();
stmt.close();
conn.close();
fileWriter.close();
```

Here field separator is comma(,) fieldEnclosure is doubleQuotes("), lineseperator is newline(\n)

I also change the memory flag value in jboss -> run.bat

Previous set `JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xms128m -Xmx1024m`

Now set `JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xms256m -Xmx3072m`

Is that a fault of run.bat file configuration? suggest some effective method if you have for same requirement.

Comment: The slow part is probably the query itself, not the actual writing of the CSV file.

Comment: @Thilo :- no bro, query taking 15sec only. file file creation start then.. i directly saw in my folder where it generating. it start and add data 15kb per sec in that file.. for 121mb its taking 3hours to complete.

Comment: Unlikely. Comment out all the CSV writing, and just read through the result set. It probably takes the same amount of time.